# Evenly vertically spaced lines inside makecell

Tags: makecell

I have a table with a rotated header, and some `makecells` afterwards to fit the rotated header on one line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
     & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Condition A}} \\
     & & A1 & A2 \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont \textbf{Condition B}}
    \rothead{\textbf{Sampling}} & \makecell{B1 \\ B2} & \makecell{xx/xx \\ xx/xx} & \makecell{xx/xx \\ xx/xx} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results under different conditions}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I'd like the text in the `makecells` to be evenly vertically spaced in the cell, rather then centred in the middle. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with ‘vertically distributed’?

Comment: As in, so they fill the cell with the same amount of space above, between and below the two lines of text rather than being clustered in the center.

Answer (score 1):

If I've well understood what you want, `\rotatebox[origin=c]` does the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\renewcommand{\cellset}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
     & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Condition A}} \\
     & & A1 & A2 \\
    \cmidrule{3-4}
   \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Sampling}} & \makecell{B1 \\ B2} & \makecell{xx/xx \\ xx/xx} & \makecell{xx/xx \\ xx/xx} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Results under different conditions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant I wanted the lines B1 // B2 etc to be evenly spaced inside the box created by the rotatebox.

Comment: @Kris: I've updated my code. The value of `\arraystretch` was found by trial and error (so you can't change it within the same table).